# Android Studio and Github missing .iml files

Tags: android, git

I'm using Android Studio version 1.5.1 and we have a problem when cloning and working with Github.
In my gitignore file I got a text saying *.iml, as I understand this means that all my iml files are ignored by git and not uploaded. When my project collaborators are cloning my project, they get a error message telling them that there is 2 missing iml files. They are asked to either keep or remove them. It doesn't matter which they do beacuse it still gives the same problem. They cannot code or build anything.

As I understand the iml files should not be uploaded to github but instead Android Studio should automaticly generate them when it is building or importing a project.

What have we done wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After cloning the repo, you should re-open the project with

> File -> Open

and select your project you've just clone and android studio will re-build, re-index and re-create the .iml file :)

[image]

Comment: AS will warn you that it is missing the .iml file(s), select Keep and it will rebuild them.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in Android Studio... 
Thanks for the solution you saved my day!

Comment: fixed yet? I just hit it!